# Detect selected checkbox in form image

Tags: python, opencv

In Brazil there is a form called DNV (after the Portuguese for "Born Alive Declaration"). I work at a Brazilian government agency that receives more than half a million of these every year from every hospital across the state.

I'm trying to detect marks on the checkbox fields. I started with the "Sex" field which has checkboxes for M (male), F (female) or I (ignored).

I'm already able to locate the field and the checkboxes with confidence using OpenCV:

[image]

I guess the checkbox region with more dark pixels is the one marked, and it works 99% of the time, even when the image quality is very low.

```
if sum(checkbox1) < sum(checkbox2):
    return "M"
else:
    return "F"
```

Sometimes this fail: a human would tell the "female" checkbox is marked, but since `sum(checkbox1)` is 577,065 and `sum(checkbox1)` is 605,880 the computer says it is a boy.

[image]

I've tried thresholding operations using several methods and values combined with morphological transforms (erode and dilate in several combinations and using many kernel shapes and sizes) and got this:

```
sex_field = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(cv2.blur(sex_field, (3, 3)), 30, 30, 15, 50)
_, sex_field = cv2.threshold(~sex_field, 127, 255, 0)
sex_field = ~cv2.morphologyEx(sex_field, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, 
                              np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=3)
```

[image]

The problem is `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising` is expensive. Is there a lighter algorithm useful for this use case?

Comment: maybe you could try to look at gradient changes inside the bounding box. Normally, if a bouding box is checked, there should be a clear difference of gradient intensity among the pixels in the box area. But I would also advise you to keep you current approach and to use the gradient thing only if there is an incertitude

Comment: I think you meant "`sum(checkbox2)` is 577,065" there

Comment: Got two flags for closing this question on the grounds that "it is not about programming". I concede it is a bit open-ended, is it best suited for another site in the stackexchange network?